# Socket.io - Easiest way to log values from the server

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

When you are testing your javascript on the server (server.js) file using socket.io, you can't use console.log(), or alert().

What is the easiest way to log or alert a value for testing purposes?

Comment: console.log() works, you will see the log in your terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use `console.log`

It just gets logged to the terminal.

[Node Docs on `console`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args)

Comment: Node docs link is broken, however I was able to find a cached version on the Wayback Machine here:  [https://web.archive.org/web/20141005210520/http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20141005210520/http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html)

Comment: Updated @Wimateeka (you could have done the same :-( )

Comment: Apologies, is it normally best practice to replace the actual link in the answer/question if it is outdated? I've seen other questions/answers where the link updates are posted in the comments and preserve/don't change the original. If it is best practice I will be sure to do so next time, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I log to `syslog` via the `node-syslog` package that way I can still see the logs even when the server is running in the background.